# IntelliJ Stuck Before Execution In Debug Mode in Mac

Tags: java, macos, debugging, intellij-idea

Running Unit tests in IntelliJ with Gradle works without any issues, but debug mode does not work. (Mac)

The debugger displays: "Listening to the connection, address: 127.0.0.1:port, transport:'socket'"

My linux setup, where debug works, shows:
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:port', transport: 'socket'

I suspect Idea fails to connect on my Mac for some reason, but comparing the two setups didn't help.

Any idea what might cause this issue?

P.S.
These are JUnit tests on the local machine (127.0.0.1).

Content of `/etc/hosts`:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Note in the log below the last exception happens when I STOP it via inteliJ (because it never stops):

```
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildCancelledException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-all.zip'.
```

Log:

```
2019-05-15 22:23:11,619 [ 127663]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2019-05-15 22:23:11,687 [ 127731]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update canceled 
2019-05-15 22:23:11,884 [ 127928]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 109ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-05-15 22:23:14,019 [ 130063]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 2135ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-05-15 22:23:14,027 [ 130071]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 79060 files to update 
2019-05-15 22:23:34,299 [ 150343]  ERROR - jediterm.terminal.TerminalMode - Mode EightBitInput is not implemented, setting to true 
2019-05-15 22:23:51,243 [ 167287]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Unindexed files update took 37216ms; general responsiveness: 0/37 sluggish, 1/37 very slow; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-05-15 22:23:51,397 [ 167441]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 146 ms spent to cache options in project 
2019-05-15 22:23:51,397 [ 167441]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Some post-startup activities freeze UI for noticeable time. Please consider making them DumbAware to do them in background under modal progress, or just making them faster to speed up project opening. 
2019-05-15 22:23:51,397 [ 167441]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Activity run in 146ms on UI thread 
2019-05-15 22:23:51,435 [ 167479]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === StatusBar ignored === 
2019-05-15 22:23:51,852 [ 167896]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - GradleJvmStartupActivity run in 396ms on UI thread 
2019-05-15 22:23:52,153 [ 168197]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 232 ms spent on EDT to cache options in project 
2019-05-15 22:24:01,454 [ 177498]   INFO - dvertisement.PluginsAdvertiser - connect timed out 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1181)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.openConnection(HttpRequests.java:609)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$300(HttpRequests.java:59)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.getConnection(HttpRequests.java:378)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.RepositoryHelper.lambda$loadPlugins$1(RepositoryHelper.java:134)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.doProcess(HttpRequests.java:523)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.process(HttpRequests.java:499)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$100(HttpRequests.java:59)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestBuilderImpl.connect(HttpRequests.java:352)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.RepositoryHelper.loadPlugins(RepositoryHelper.java:129)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.RepositoryHelper.loadPlugins(RepositoryHelper.java:93)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.RepositoryHelper.loadPlugins(RepositoryHelper.java:84)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.RepositoryHelper.loadPluginsFromAllRepositories(RepositoryHelper.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.pluginsAdvertisement.PluginsAdvertiser$4.run(PluginsAdvertiser.java:292)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2019-05-15 22:24:16,955 [ 192999]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - git log took 10861 ms. Command parameters: 
/usr/bin/nice -n 10 /usr/local/bin/git -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false -c diff.renameLimit=1000 log --no-walk=unsorted --stdin --pretty=format:%x01%x01%H%x02%x02%ct%x02%x02%an%x02%x02%at%x02%x02%ae%x02%x02%cn%x02%x02%ce%x02%x02%P%x02%x02%s%x02%x02%b%x02%x02%B%x03%x03 --encoding=UTF-8 -M --name-status -m -- 
2019-05-15 22:24:18,521 [ 194565]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home 
2019-05-15 22:24:18,522 [ 194566]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home 
2019-05-15 22:24:18,649 [ 194693]   INFO - ration.services.NativeServices - Initialized native services in: /Users/xxxx/.gradle/native 
2019-05-15 22:24:18,654 [ 194698]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: --tests xx.xx.xx.xx.xxxx.xxxx--init-script /private/var/folders/n5/2sn82k_15qng22jw2tyqfrdc0000gn/T/ijresolvers.gradle 
2019-05-15 22:24:41,078 [ 217122]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - git log took 21833 ms. Command parameters: 
/usr/bin/nice -n 10 /usr/local/bin/git -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false -c diff.renameLimit=1000 log --no-walk=unsorted --stdin --pretty=format:%x01%x01%H%x02%x02%ct%x02%x02%an%x02%x02%at%x02%x02%ae%x02%x02%cn%x02%x02%ce%x02%x02%P%x02%x02%s%x02%x02%b%x02%x02%B%x03%x03 --encoding=UTF-8 -M --name-status -m -- 
2019-05-15 22:25:05,377 [ 241421]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - The DialogWrapper can only be used in event dispatch thread. Current thread: Thread[external task forked debugger runner,6,Idea Thread Group] 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The DialogWrapper can only be used in event dispatch thread. Current thread: Thread[external task forked debugger runner,6,Idea Thread Group]
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.ensureEventDispatchThread(DialogWrapper.java:2152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.init(DialogWrapper.java:1260)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.SingleConfigurableEditor.<init>(SingleConfigurableEditor.java:57)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.SingleConfigurableEditor.<init>(SingleConfigurableEditor.java:91)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.SingleConfigurableEditor.<init>(SingleConfigurableEditor.java:103)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunDialog$1.<init>(RunDialog.java:104)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunDialog.editConfiguration(RunDialog.java:104)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunDialog.editConfiguration(RunDialog.java:99)
    at com.intellij.execution.ProgramRunnerUtil.executeConfigurationAsync(ProgramRunnerUtil.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.execution.ForkedDebuggerThread.attachVM(ForkedDebuggerThread.java:207)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.execution.ForkedDebuggerThread.handleForkedProcessSignal(ForkedDebuggerThread.java:136)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.execution.ForkedDebuggerThread.run(ForkedDebuggerThread.java:103)
2019-05-15 22:25:05,378 [ 241422]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.5  Build #IU-183.5912.21 
2019-05-15 22:25:05,378 [ 241422]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2019-05-15 22:25:05,378 [ 241422]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Mac OS X 
2019-05-15 22:25:09,785 [ 245829]   INFO - g.FileBasedIndexProjectHandler - Reindexing refreshed files: 0 to update, calculated in 0ms 
2019-05-15 22:25:14,205 [ 250249]   INFO - .openapi.util.LowMemoryWatcher - Low memory signal received: afterGc=false 
2019-05-15 22:25:18,796 [ 254840]   INFO - g.FileBasedIndexProjectHandler - Reindexing refreshed files: 47 to update, calculated in 1ms 
2019-05-15 22:25:18,867 [ 254911]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Reindexing refreshed files took 71ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-05-15 22:26:06,032 [ 302076]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home 
2019-05-15 22:26:16,152 [ 312196]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-all.zip'. 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-all.zip'.
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.ProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:427)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:151)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:151)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:151)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.JavaGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(JavaGradleProjectResolver.java:94)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:151)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:151)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.task.GradleTaskManager.lambda$executeTasks$0(GradleTaskManager.java:128)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:217)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.task.GradleTaskManager.executeTasks(GradleTaskManager.java:134)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.task.GradleTaskManager.executeTasks(GradleTaskManager.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemTaskManagerImpl.lambda$executeTasks$0(RemoteExternalSystemTaskManagerImpl.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemTaskManagerImpl.executeTasks(RemoteExternalSystemTaskManagerImpl.java:47)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemTaskManagerWrapper.executeTasks(ExternalSystemTaskManagerWrapper.java:52)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemExecuteTaskTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemExecuteTaskTask.java:172)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:166)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.execution.ExternalSystemRunConfiguration$MyRunnableState.lambda$execute$0(ExternalSystemRunConfiguration.java:431)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildCancelledException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:77)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.task.GradleTaskManager.lambda$executeTasks$0(GradleTaskManager.java:118)
    ... 16 more
```

Please see attached image
[image]

Image from terminal:
[image]

IDEA version: 2018.3.5 Ultimate Edition

Comment: Could you please attach content of your /etc/hosts file and screenshots of used run configurations?

Comment: @y.bedrov sure. Updated with `/etc/hosts`. Is there specific screen you wan to see in configuration?

Comment: Please try to comments all records in hosts file except "127.0.0.1 localhost"

Comment: @y.bedrov still stuck.

Comment: Could you please clarify if debug starts after stuck or not?

Comment: @y.bedrov debug did not start after the change; it was the same behavior.

Comment: Could you share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue? Also please attach screenshots of used run configurations (only "Configuration" tab)

Comment: @y.bedrov sure, please see attached.

Comment: Looks like some issue with Gradle. Is it possibel to share sample project example, so I could check it on my side?

Comment: @y.bedrov not sure how to share a sample project; let me see if I can create one with similar gradle settings. Execution in non debug mode works fine, so it’s odd that gradle might be the source.